# Sorting child pages as they are created

Tags: confluence

I am newbie in Confluence and I want to know how how can we sort child pages in the side bar as they are created.

Child pages are now displaying in alphabetical order. I just created multiple child pages, like "January", "February", "March", "April".

It's displaying in the following order:

1. April
2. February
3. January
4. March

I want them in the following order:

1. January
2. February
3. March
4. April

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort child pages manually - see [Changing the page order manually](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF51/Changing+the+Sequential+Order+of+Pages)

> Changing the page order manually
>
> To change the order of pages in the space:
>
> 1. Go to a page in the space and choose Pages in the sidebar. For more options, choose Browse and reorder all pages.
>    Or, if you are using the Documentation theme, choose Browse > Pages at the top of the screen.
> 2. Choose Browse and Reorder Pages (default theme only).
> 3. Expand the branches of the tree to find the page family you wish to sort.
> 4. Drag each page to a new position in the tree.
>
> When you drag a page to a new position, the order of the page family
> changes to Manual.  Newly added pages will not be sorted
> alphabetically, but will appear at the bottom of the list.

Comment: For newer editions of Confluence, see https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/move-and-reorder-pages-146407727.html